# Show tooltip over a second graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I'm trying to make a large tooltip appear above another graph. At this time it is shown below. In [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/silviokucharski/go1eem4h/4/) you can try. In this example, the size of the letter and the spaces to generate the situation are exaggerated. What you really need is to display the tooltip above the second graph and not reduce the size of the tooltip.

This is a part of my code:

```
.highcharts-container {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
svg {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
.myTooltip{
    z-index: 500;
}
```

[Highcharts graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfU6J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
}
#container2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

The tooltip is below as its parent is also below ...